# Permutations with data.table join

Tags: r, data.table, combinatorics

Below is a table of products customer 1 has bought.

```
df <- data.table(customer_id = rep(1,3)
                 , product_1 = letters[1:3]
                  )

   customer_id product_1
1:           1         a
2:           1         b
3:           1         c
```

Assume the real dataset has multiple customers, I'd like to, for each customer, create a *permutation* of products each has bought (without replacement). In combinatorics term:

```
nPk
```

where

n = number of (distinct) products each customer has bought

k = 2

Results:

```
customer_id product_1 product_2
1:           1         a         b
2:           1         a         c
3:           1         b         c
4:           1         b         a
5:           1         c         a
6:           1         c         b
```

The SQL join conditions would be:

```
where   customer_id = customer_id
        and product_1 != product_1
```

However, I understand `data.table` currently has [limited support for non equi joins](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1799). Therefore, is there an alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: this can be done with non equi joins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can eliminate the cases where `product_1` and `product_2` are equal after joining

```
df[df, on = .(customer_id = customer_id), allow.cartesian = T
   ][product_1 != i.product_1
     ][order(product_1)]

   customer_id product_1 i.product_1
1:           1         a           b
2:           1         a           c
3:           1         b           a
4:           1         b           c
5:           1         c           a
6:           1         c           b
```

Comment: Thank you @Humpelstielzchen
Why is it that `data.table` does not allow the below?

`df[df, on = .(customer_id = customer_id
                      , product_1 != i.product_1), allow.cartesian = T
           ]`
thus, necessitates chaining?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea why there's no `!=` in `data.table` join syntax

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `by=.EACHI`:

```
df[df, on=.(customer_id), 
    .(p1=i.product_1, p2=x.product_1[x.product_1!=i.product_1]), by=.EACHI]
```

output:

```
   customer_id p1 p2
1:           1  a  b
2:           1  a  c
3:           1  b  a
4:           1  b  c
5:           1  c  a
6:           1  c  b
```

Comment: This does work also. However, the method (syntax) is new to me. I would need to parse it myself. Thank you @chinsoon12

Answer (score 1):

Using same logic as @Humpelstielzchen, in `dplyr` we can use `full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df, df, by = "customer_id") %>% filter(product_1.x != product_1.y)


#  customer_id product_1.x product_1.y
#1           1           a           b
#2           1           a           c
#3           1           b           a
#4           1           b           c
#5           1           c           a
#6           1           c           b
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ronak I am looking for a `data.table` solution on this occassion for performance. Though much appreciated